# Union by multiple basic types

Tags: typescript

```
export type CustomProps<T> = {
  value: string | number | boolean;
  entity: T;
};
```

I've created type , which have `value` prop, and it can take `string, number, boolean` , but when I try to use it , and assign to `value` for example one of those types `value: string` , it says me

> Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Code:

```
interface Props {
  entity: BankI;
  value: string;
}

const Value = ({ value, entity }: Props) => {
  const id = useMemo(() => generateUuid() + entity._id, [entity._id]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <p className={styles.body1} id={id}>
        {value}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const object = {
        // Error occurs in this line on <Value /> component
        custom: (props: CustomProps<BankI>) => <Value {...props} />,
}
```

Error occurs, where I call `Value` component , Value component have props , which showed above , in proops I assign string type to value, my type CustomProps should take `value` as one of types `(string, boolean, number)`

Comment: Can you show code where you attempt to assign

Comment: You'll need some kind of narrowing. We'll help you if you share a bit more code.

Comment: Shared code snippets

Comment: Where in the snippets does the error occur? The snippets do not feel sufficient and complete

Comment: Added comment where error occurs, where I call Value component , Value component have props , which showed above , in proops I assign string type to value, my type CustomProps should take value as one of types(string, boolean, number) , error attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different approaches you can take to get around this. One would be to add a type parameter to `CustomProps` which specifies the type of `value`:

```js
export type CustomProps<T, V extends string | number | boolean> = {
  value: V;
  entity: T;
};
```

The other approach would be to add a discriminator field that indicates what the value type is, like so:

```js
export interface CustomPropsBase<T> {
  entity: T;
}

export interface StringCustomProps<T> extends CustomPropsBase<T> {
  valueType: 'string';
  value: string;
}

export interface BooleanCustomProps<T> extends CustomPropsBase<T> {
  valueType: 'bool';
  value: boolean;
}

export interface NumberCustomProps<T> extends CustomPropsBase<T> {
  valueType: 'number';
  value: number;
}

export type CustomProps<T> = StringCustomProps<T> | BooleanCustomProps<T> | NumberCustomProps<T>;
```

With the second approach, TypeScript will automatically know when you check `valueType` what the type of `value` is, e.g.:

```js
function myFunc(customProp: customProps<Foo>) {
  if (customProp.valueType === 'string') {
    // Typescript knows `value` is string
    let str: string = customProp.value;
  }
}
```

You would set the `valueType` when you create the `CustomProps` instance to match the type you are using, e.g.:

```js
let x: StringCustomProps<Foo> = {
  entity: myFooObj,
  value: 'My string value',
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Comment: First example I like , but how it differ from my code ? Difference will be CustomProps<BankI, string> , and when i will to it , it show me same error it showed before

Comment: If you have a `CustomProps<Bank, string>` you should be able to assign its `value` to a `string` with no problem; are you sure you got the same error?

Comment: ok , sorry , it works  ) thanks, way my mystake

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out. Please mark this as the accepted answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: could you also describe this huck ? isn't it the same as I was doing ?

Comment: The difference between this and what you were doing is that the extra type parameter forces you to specify the type at compile time, e.g. `CustomProps<Bank, string>`, so TypeScript knows in each instance which type you are using.